# Using AngularJs Template value in Spring Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I want to use the angularJs Template value in spring Controller.

If it is like

```
ng-model=x
```

and we show the data with `{{x}}`

how can I use this **x value** in a Spring Rest Controller's method as a parameter?

Comment: You can send `x` as parameter to controller.

Comment: How ? there i am struggling

Comment: Try some research with `@RequestParam`, `@PathVariable`, `@RequestBody` etc ...

Comment: Thanks for the clue

Comment: @TheKojuEffect Solved it

Comment: Good for you Gourab. Looks good. (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the Issue .

Here is the Answer:

if in **AngularJs**( *in the HTML templete*) is `{{x}}`

then in spring RestController we can use with @RequestParam

Therefore ,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/TheAddress",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public TheName(@RequestBody String anystring,
                     @RequestParam("x") String asThevaliableToUseInTheControler) {

//The code
}
```

Comment: plus one for posting for solution.